# SQL Server CDC - Snapshot from specific date for Debezium Kafka

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We are enabling CDC on specific tables in our MSSQL. We are connecting to a pipeline of migrating data through `MSSQL->CDC->DEBEZIUM->KAFKA_CONNECT`

There is a table that has more than a million rows, but we need only a few thousand rows from the  table to be included in the Snapshot Created when enabling CDC.
The reason why I don't want to handle it in our Kafka-Consumer is because, while I need just 1% of the data to be written to Mongo, rest 99% is gonna hit the consumer without any use.

---

Questions:

1. Is it possible to create snapshot of specific rows/views while enabling CDC. I need rows which have column_value(modified date)>a specific date?
2. Is this too much of micro-optimisation and I shall let everything come and hit the pipeline and be rejected by the consumer instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Kafka Connect Single Message Transform (SMT)](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/f). More precisely, you need the [`Filter`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/filter.html) SMT:

> The `filter.condition` is a predicate specifying JSON path that is
>   applied to each record processed, and when this predicate successfully
>   matches the record is either included (when `filter.type=include`) or
>   excluded (when `filter.type=exclude`)

---

In your case, you can **include** rows that satisfy your desired condition:

```
transforms=filter-records
transforms.filterExample1.type=io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value
transforms.filterExample1.filter.condition=$.value[?(@.modified_date > "1/1/2020")]
transforms.filterExample1.filter.type=include
transforms.filterExample1.missing.or.null.behavior=fail
```

---

Alternatively, you can decide which rows to **exclude**:

```
transforms=filter-records
transforms.filterExample1.type=io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value
transforms.filterExample1.filter.condition=$.value[?(@.modified_date <= "1/1/2020")]
transforms.filterExample1.filter.type=exclude
transforms.filterExample1.missing.or.null.behavior=fail
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Giorgos, is this generic or relevant only to Confluent Kafka, because we use Amazon MSK Kafka Setup, does this apply to that as well? Also, can you share the docs if you could find? I am not able to. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @UdayaPrakash Kafka Connect (and hence SMTs) is part of the open source kafka (as well as with the confluent distribution). Wrt to the docs, I have already shared a couple of links to the documentation.

Comment: I'll try it out and approve if it works, Thanks Giorgos, much appreciated

Comment: Can these SMTs be used on Debezium Kafka Connect connector? Does it work out of the box with Debezium and Kafka Connect? I have never used SMTs. TIA!

Comment: @UdayaPrakash As I already mentioned, Kafka Connect as well as SMTs are part of the open source kafka distribution (see docs: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms) so they work with Debezium as well. For example, refer to this page: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/configuration/event-flattening.html

Comment: There is another option available too - see https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/configuration/filtering.html